# Error in manifest when i try to install my android app

Tags: android, installation, android-manifest, manifest

I have the next error when I am trying to install my android application to a virtual device (I couldn't test in a real phone).

> **INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED**

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="developer.negabur.chistes" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="Business.Categorias"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your activity name needs to be prefixed with a period, like the following

```
android:name=".BusinessCategorias"
```

Comment: `android:name` needs to be the exact name of your activity class